# Angular 2 - how to load component dynamically from another service

Tags: angularjs, rest, angular

I know the usecase is a bit weird, but i need to load component from another system via rest json respond, and insert that to my application. (it is basically a widget, what will be added by our client)

that rest service should return the 'component itself', and the 'data' what will need to that component.

Im sure I should use ComponentResolver somehow...

I am still not sure whether it is even possible... 
can i even resolve a text (comp comes from rest service) hat has a typescript content?

thanks a lot

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36325212/angular-2-dynamic-tabs-with-user-click-chosen-components/36325468#36325468

Comment: in this example the dynamically imported classes are at the same class with the component... 
how would you resolve if you know only runtime what component need to be imported? eg: i need to import /widgets/123/version/122.ts

Comment: Sorry, I don't know about dynamically importing. Maybe there is something systemjs or webpack offer. I'm using Dart and don't know much about TS tools.